# load into Fact Table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

i have four dimension tables (titles,publishers,stores,period) and i like to load data into a fact table but i didn't know how! by the way i'm using SSIS 
and in the measures of this fact table i have Qty and turnover(chiffre d'affaire) that i need to calculate but i din't know how to. plus in my source data i have in every date a qty. 
i want to know which ssis tools i need to use to achieve that + calculating the measures. 
i calculate qte from sources but it don't give me to every row a qte. it gives me qte of all in one row!!
[image: this is my dimension table which are i already load into them data]
[image: this is one of my source data]
[image: this is my fact table (empty)]
[image: this is ;y fact table]

[image: this how i'm suppose to calculate my turnover]

Comment: Does your input data come from EXCEL file?

Comment: yes from excel, flat file and database pubs

Comment: Have you loaded data into the dimension tables yet?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, i did

Comment: Have you created the target fact table? Can you post it's definition? Can you describe how the 'turnover' measure should be calculated? For starters have a look through this: https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/how-to-populate-a-fact-table-using-ssis-part1/ , particularly the diagram under _Build the SSIS Package to Populate the Fact Table_. Although I generally don't recommend the use of lookups, they're OK for small data volumes. Once you do that we have some idea of what you need help with. You need to narrow down your problem to something more specific

Comment: @Nick check my updated

Comment: Is `TF_CA` your fact table? A fact table _normally_ has surrogate keys but you're a long way off that. What's stopping you loading that excel file into that table right now?

Comment: @Nick the problem is i don't only have an excel file, i have a flat file and database pubs! so i don't know to load them all!!!!

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you need to load data out of three sources (excel, text, database?) Then put three sources into your data flow. You need to take a step back and understand and explain your problem more thoroughly. You didn't mention any of this in your original question. At this stage you have also not explained how to calculate turnover.

Comment: this is how we calculate turnover (SUM(Qte*price)). the problem that i found is how join Qte and price in one table . cause they are in 2 differnet tables

Comment: Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp it explains inner joins. That's what you need. You need to read that page, then you probably need to read the whole w3c SQL tutorial, then you need to explain about your sources. Then you might make some progress.

Comment: @Nick Thnak you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very basic, so I suggest you to take your time and look at some SSIS tutorials on youtube or:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-create-a-project-and-basic-package-with-ssis

To answer your question though: you need to first add a Data Flow Task into your Control Flow. Double click on the DFT and in the Data Flow, add an Excel Source to connect to your source. If you want to do some calculations, you need to use a Derived Column transformation.